# regex find one or two digits but not three digits in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to find the match for:
\024jack3hall**2**\c$
\024jack3hall**02**\c$
\024jack3hall**12**\c$
but not for:
\024jack3hall**023**\c$
difference is the number of digits in the end part. I would like to have only 1 or 2, not 3.
my try:

```
 \\\\024[a-zA-Z0-9]+[0-9]{1,2}\\[a-zA-Z]{1}\$(?!.)
```

I tried only on http://regexr.com/ but will implement in C#.
Is it possible to edit my try or I have to write several separate checks?
Why is

```
 {1,2}
```

not working? \024jack3hall**12343**\c$ is also matching,

Comment: So which parts of this are constant and which change? All your example start with `\024jack3hal`, but it looks like, from your regex, only the `024` part is constant. They also all end `\c$`, but it looks like the `c` isn't constant

Comment: @Matt, \\024 is constant, after this is name of PC actually and it can be letters or letters with number inside, always ending with number-one or two digit, then drive letter(custom) with constant $ on ending and nothing further

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From *the examples you have shown*, something as simple as:

```
[^\d](\d{1,2})\\
```

Should work. It will match 1 or 2 digits followed by a `\` so long as it isn't proceeded by another digit. 
The matched digits are in a capture group if you need them (or you can just remove the brackets if you don't need that).

As for your original effort, right here:

```
\\\\024[a-zA-Z0-9]+[0-9]{1,2}
```

You are matching 1 or more from the range `a-z`, `A-Z` **or** `0-9`. So that will match your extra digits if they come at the end of that pattern.

Comment: In the context of .NET, `\d` matches digits from other languages, such as "٦" - unless RegexOptions.ECMAScript is specified. It's unlikely to matter for the OP's question, but it is something to watch out for.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
\\\\024[a-zA-Z0-9]+[^\d](\d{1,2})\\[a-zA-Z]{1}\$(?!.)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you were not escaping backslash properly.
Here is the correct regex:

```
\\024[a-zA-Z0-9]+[0-9]{1,2}\\[a-zA-Z]{1}\$(?!.)
```

Answer (score 0):

The ***general idea to restrict a specific amount of digits inside a pattern*** is by using **numeric boundaries**:

```
(?<!\d)\d{min,max}(?!\d)
```

So, to match one or two digits but not three, you'd use `(?<!\d)\d{1,2}(?!\d)`, or an ASCII-only version, `(?<![0-9])[0-9]{1,2}(?![0-9])`.

Certainly, in case the digit pattern is preceded or followed with non-digit matching patterns, you do not need these boundaries. E.g. `[a-zA-Z]+\d{min,max}\s+\w+`. Of course, neither `[a-zA-Z]` nor `\s` match digits, so the amount of digits matched with `\d{min,max}` is safely restricted to the specified values.

Now, the **current OP solution** can look like

```
\\\\024[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z][0-9]{1,2}\\[a-zA-Z]\$
\\\\024[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?<![0-9])[0-9]{1,2}\\[a-zA-Z]\$
```

The first one assures the right amount of digits since the `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` (one or more letters or digits) is turned into `[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z]` (zero or more letters or digits and then a letter). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yHCALf/1).

The second one utilizes the left-hand digit boundary, `(?<![0-9])`. Note that `(?<!\d)` can also be used here safely, too. There is no need to use a right-hand digit boundary since `\\` pattern only matches a backslash (and can't match a digit). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yHCALf/2).